# Strange integration result

Tags: polynomials

In Mathematica 8, the Integrate command sometimes strangely integrates polynomials yielding unsimplified (and unexpected) fractional results. As an example, the line:

```
Integrate[((h-x)*(q[1]+q[2])+x*(q[3]+q[4]))^2,{x,0,h}]
```

The (unsimplified) result is:

```
h^2/3(-(q[1]+q[2])^3+(q[3]+q[4])^3)/(-q[1]+q[2]+q[3]+q[4])
```

while the (theoretical) result cannot be a fraction. What are the proper command lines which lead to a polynomial?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: The result is not supposed to be a fraction. Is there a command that would help in that direction?

Comment: Try `Integrate[...] // Expand // Simplify`. The reason for this is that the expression with fractions has a smaller `LeafCount` (39) than your expected result (43).

Comment: *Strangely* is too subjective for what you described. Maybe it's better to externalize your state. And, as Rojo asked, you didn't make yourself clear what you want.

Comment: Question edited.

Comment: @pluton You might also try `Collect[Integrate[ ...], x]` to express the result explicitly as a polynomial, although with very complicated coefficients. I'm not sure what you mean when you say that "The result is not *supposed* to be a fraction"

Comment: As @R.M Said, it's becuase the `LeafCount` is the important criterion for complexity. You can just replace `q[1]` with `q1` and so on.

Comment: @MarkMcClure: the result is not supposed to be a fraction 'of the coefficients' of the integrated polynomial.

Comment: Use Together[] on the result.     InputForm[Together[Integrate[((h-x)*(q[1]+q[2])+x*(q[3]+q[4]))^2,{x,0,h}]]]

Out[5]//InputForm= 
(h^3*(q[1]^2 + 2*q[1]*q[2] + q[2]^2 + q[1]*q[3] + q[2]*q[3] + q[3]^2 + 
   q[1]*q[4] + q[2]*q[4] + 2*q[3]*q[4] + q[4]^2))/3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `Expand` and `Simplify` to get your expected result (without fractions):

```
Integrate[((h - x)*(q[1] + q[2]) + x*(q[3] + q[4]))^2, {x, 0, h}] // Expand // Simplify
(* 1/3 h^3 (q[1]^2 + q[2]^2 + q[2] (q[3] + q[4]) + (q[3] + q[4])^2 + q[1] (2 q[2] + q[3] + q[4])) *)
```

The reason *Mathematica* displayed the form with fractions is because it has a smaller [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LeafCount.html) than your expected answer:

```
1/3 h^3 (q[1]^2 + q[2]^2 + q[2] (q[3] + q[4]) + (q[3] + q[4])^2 + 
    q[1] (2 q[2] + q[3] + q[4])) // LeafCount
(* 43 *)

(h^3 (-(q[1] + q[2])^3 + (q[3] + q[4])^3))/(3 (-q[1] - q[2] + q[3] + q[4])) // LeafCount
(* 39 *)
```

All the `q[i]`s introduce additional leaves. If you had done the same integration differently, you'd have gotten the result you were expecting:

```
Integrate[((h - x)*(p + q) + x*(r + s))^2, {x, 0, h}]
(* 1/3 h^3 (p^2 + q^2 + q (r + s) + (r + s)^2 + p (2 q + r + s)) *)
```

This has a `LeafCount` of 32.

Comment: What about just `Cancel`? +1 btw

Comment: @Rojo `Cancel` works too, but has a much higher leaf count

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own `ComplexityFunction` to emphasize your avoidance of complex fractions:

```
compfunc[e_] := Total@Cases[e, Power[expr_, -1] :> LeafCount[expr], {0, Infinity}] +
                LeafCount[e]

Integrate[((h - x)*(q[1] + q[2]) + x*(q[3] + q[4]))^2, {x, 0, h}] // 
  FullSimplify[#, ComplexityFunction -> compfunc] &
```

> 1/3 h^3 (q[1]^2 + q[2]^2 + q[2] (q[3] + q[4]) + (q[3] + q[4])^2 + 
>      q[1] (2 q[2] + q[3] + q[4]))